# Create email in c# using Mailkit and send later in Outlook ActiveSync

Tags: c#, email, outlook, mailkit, activesync

I am currently creating emails with Mailkit in c# and I append it to an own folder. When I try to send the email from the server or in Outlook with IMAP or Exchange connector, it works fine. But when I try to send the email with Outlook ActiveSync, the send button is missing and I cannot find a way to send the message. Do you have any idea?

```
using (var client = new ImapClient())
{
    String email = "";
    String password = "";
    String server = "";
    
    client.Connect(server, 993, true);
    client.Authenticate(email, password);
    
    var inbox = client.GetFolder(client.PersonalNamespaces[0]);
    var testfolder = inbox.Create("Testfolder", true);
    
    var reply = new MimeMessage();
    reply.From.Add(new MailboxAddress("Test", email));
    reply.To.Add(new MailboxAddress("Test", ""));
    reply.Subject = "Testemail";
    
    var bodyBuilder = new BodyBuilder();
    bodyBuilder.HtmlBody = "";
    reply.Body = bodyBuilder.ToMessageBody();

    testfolder.Append(reply, MessageFlags.Draft);
    
    client.Disconnect(true);
}
```

I would expect the send button as in Outlook with Exchange connector:
[Send Button available](https://i.stack.imgur.com/h2eeQ.png)

But an email is created in the folder that I am unable to send:
[No send Button available](https://i.stack.imgur.com/idlJ2.png)

Answer (score 0):

That is because Outlook treats your message as sent. Make sure to add `X-Unsent: 1` MIME header.

Comment: Thank you, this makes absolutely sense. I tried it but it is still not working, the send button is missing.

Comment: Have you tried to compare your message to an unsent message created by Outlook?

Comment: Unfortunately, I am not able to see the message header of a draft message that I have created in Outlook

Comment: Why not? If you already have an IMAP4 connection to the server,why can't you read any message there?

Comment: I have connected my account to Outlook with ActiveSync, not IMAP4. The draft folder is only locally and I do not have this message in the draft folder on the server.

Comment: If your code is running locally, why not use the Outlook Object Model?

Comment: It really seems to be a problem with Outlook Exchange Active Sync (EAS). I was able to reproduce the problem by creating an email manually on outlook server and then moved the draft email to another folder. In Outlook Active Sync I cannot send the email anymore.